# How can I change existing hierarchy in Unity regarding animations?

Tags: unity, animation

I made a bunch of animations in Unity.  Now I need to adjust the hierarchy.  For example:

My animator used to change things in this tree, where the head, legs, and arms were animated:

```
Player
-->Torso
----->Head
----->Arms
----->Legs
```

Now I added another layer in my hierarchy so that it is:

```
Player
-->Body
----->Torso
-------->Head
-------->Arms
-------->Legs
```

And it cannot find the existing animation, since the hierarchy path is different.  How can I insert the body in my animation hierarchy so that I can keep my new hierarchy without having to redo all of the animation?

Comment: If you're using Legacy animations, set your serialisation mode to Force Text and open the animation file in a text editor. You might be able to inject the new hierarchy level by modifying the text. (Posting as a comment because I don't have a full recipe or validated test case for this approach)

Comment: @DMGregory thanks. Not using legacy mode, but still a good thought. I'll see if I can't find some data in the current system.